# "Offline" (CDROM) Package Repository

Tags: installation, apt

I am running a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server on a private network that doesn't and never will have internet access.

I have a need to install packages from time to time for development purposes, and rather than download the .deb files everytime to manual install i would like to create an offline repository in the form of an .ISO that i can present to my VM's in ESXI.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I assume once i have them on a CD i can add the mounted ISO to apt sources.list?

Answer (score 0):

Try following the instructions from [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository). Basically, you need to:

1. Connect the storage medium to the computer with Internet access
2. Go to [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) and select the codename of the version of Ubuntu installed on the computer without Internet access.
3. Download the files, Release, Release.jpg, and the content files for your architecture
4. Go to the component and your computer's architecture
5. Download the packages, Packages.bz2, Packages.gz, and Release
6. Connect your storage medium to your offline computer
7. Under Software Sources, add your offline repository

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.